# Dartboard centered at origin has radius 20. Let (X,Y) be the random location of dart thrown. Find c and P(Hitting a bullseye)

Tags: probability

The joint probability density function is defined by:

$c(20-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le20$
$0$ if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>20$

Find c
If the bullseye is the center of the radius 1 find the probability the player hits a bullseye.

$\int_{-20}^{20}\int_{-20}^{20}c(20-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dxdy=1$

This is initially what I thought the bounds for the integral would be. It's slightly off cause if x=20 or -20 then y can only be 0 but I don't really know how to accurately represent that in the integral. Because I did it this way I got some super weird value for c, but I know once I get c then the probability of hitting a bullseye should be

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1c(20-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dydx$$

Comment: This problem is much easier if you work in polar coordinates.

Comment: how would you do this with polars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading the problem correctly, you are assuming that the dart's position falls off in proportion to the distance from the center.  Then the probability that the dart hits within $R$ units of the center is proportional to
$$
P(R) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{R} (20 - r)r dr d\theta
= 2\pi\left( 10R^2- \frac{R^3}{3}\right) .
$$
That must be normalized to make the value $1$ when $R=20$ since you assume the player doesn't miss the target entirely. That normalization  tells you $c$.

For the bulls-eye probability you don't have to find $c$  since what you want is the ratio 
$$ 
\frac{P(1)}{P(20)} = 0.00725 .
$$

That's less than $1\%$ (if I did the integration and the arithmetic correctly). I think a real dart player would have a radial function that dropped off faster toward the edge of the target.

Comment: yes your assumptions are correct and your answer seems reasonable